# Critical point in 2D Potts model and duality equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ising-model, statics

I have to prove, considering the limits of high and low temperatures, duality equation:
$$
Z=q e^{2 N K} F\left(e^{-K}\right)=q^{-N}\left(e^{K}+q-1\right)^{2 N} F\left(\frac{e^{K}-1}{e^{K}+q-1}\right)
$$
for square lattice with
$$Z=\sum_{\sigma_{1}, \sigma_{N}} \prod_{<i j>} e^{K \delta_{\sigma_{i} \sigma_{j}}}$$
where $<ij>$ are neighboring atoms and $\sigma_{i} \epsilon$ $\{1,2, \ldots, q\}$. **Also i have information that there is only one critical point.**

I can try to make analog of low and high temperature Kramers–Wannier duality, let's assume we have **s** horizontally and **r** vertically pairs of different spins, then low temperature decomposition looks like:
$$
\exp \left(K \sum_{<i j>} \delta_{\sigma_{i} \sigma_{j}}\right)=\exp ((s+r)K)$$
But I have problems with high temperature decomposition:
$$
e^{K \delta_{\sigma_{i} \sigma_{j}}}=\cosh \left(\frac{1+\sigma \sigma^{\prime}}{2}K\right)+\frac{1+\sigma \sigma^{\prime}}{2}\sinh (K)
$$

Comment: "I have to prove..." Why do you have to?

Comment: i forgot to add tag homework, sorry

Comment: What textbook are you using for the class?

Comment: lecture 2 from my university department http://slava.itp.ac.ru/intro-to-integrable-lattice-models/ but you will not understand this language

Comment: I don't understand your high-temperature decomposition. I would have written the latter as $e^{K\delta_{\sigma_i\sigma_j}} = 1 + (e^K-1) \delta_{\sigma_i\sigma_j}$.

Answer (score 1):

The duality equation can be proved using the Fortuin-Kasteleyn representation of the Potts model. Introduce link variables $b_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$ to rewrite the partition function as
$$\eqalign{
   Z&=\sum_{\{\sigma\}} \prod_{(i,j)} e^{K\delta_{\sigma_i,\sigma_j}}\cr
   &=\sum_{\{\sigma\}} \prod_{(i,j)} \big[e^K\delta_{\sigma_i,\sigma_j}
   +e^0(1-\delta_{\sigma_i,\sigma_j})\big]\cr
   &=\sum_{\{\sigma\}} \prod_{(i,j)}\Big[\sum_{b_{ij}=0}^1\big(
   (e^K-1)\delta_{\sigma_i,\sigma_j}\delta_{b_{ij},1}+\delta_{b_{ij},0}\Big]
   }$$
The variables $b_{ij}$ form a graph on the lattice. The sum over the spins
$\sigma$ can now be performed leaving
$$Z=\sum_{G} u^{b(G)} q^{C(G)}$$
where $u=e^K-1$, $b(G)=\sum b_{ij}$ is the number of edges in the graph $G$ and $C(G)$ is the number of clusters. The duality transformation consists in associating to each link $b_{ij}$ on the lattice a dual link $b_{ij}^*=1-b_{ij}$ on the dual lattice. Each loops on the dual lattice encloses a cluster on the lattice. Using Euler relations, one finally gets the duality relation. For more details, see Ref. 2.

References:

1. Fortuin, C.M.; Kasteleyn, P.W. (1972). "On the random-cluster model : I. Introduction and relation to other models". Physica. 57 (4): 536–564. doi:10.1016/0031-8914(72)90045-6
2. G. Grimmett (2006) The Random Cluster Model, Springer-Verlag